# what is the file encoding type for java class file?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, .class-file

What is the file encoding type used for Java class files?

I am not referring to the `file.encoding` or `Charset.defaultCharset()` properties.

When `javac` compiles a `.java` file to a `.class` file and saves the resulting file on disk, what file encoding type is used? Is it UTF-8?

Can someone provide more details on this? I do not want to make assumptions.

Comment: the one you specified. For .java files, check the javac doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: I imagine this would entirely depend on your text-editor, or IDE.  For example, I'm using UTF-8, here.

Comment: You will most probably (can't account for *all* compilers) find that the *strings* inside the class file will end up as UTF-8 irrespective of your source file encoding

Comment: @g00se - `strings inside the class file will end up as UTF-8 irrespective of your source file encoding` good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Java compiles a `.java` source file into a `.class` file, the resulting `.class` file does not use a specific file encoding type like UTF-8. Instead, it follows a binary format known as the Java class file format.

The Java class file format is designed to be platform-independent and is primarily intended to be consumed by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). It contains a structured set of bytes that represent various elements of the compiled Java code, such as class declarations, methods, fields, and bytecode instructions.

The class file format specifies a specific layout and organization of bytes, including headers, constant pools, access flags, attribute tables, and more. It does not rely on any specific character encoding scheme like `UTF-8` because the content of a class file consists of compiled Java bytecode instructions, numeric values, and symbolic references rather than human-readable text.

Therefore, when you compile a Java source file using the `javac` compiler, the resulting `.class` file is not encoded as text but as binary data conforming to the Java class file format.

Comment: @Vamsh It's completely inappropriate to ask others to upvote your own question. Don't do that.

Comment: @skomisa, to upvote good answers, i need 50 reps. thats the point. If at all.. try to encourage new bees on the platform.

Comment: @Vamsh You should earn your reputation by posting good questions and good answers, not by pestering users to upvote you. Don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

Encoding refers to text, not binary data.

Class files are binary data - so there's no *notion* of a text encoding for them, any more than there is for an MP3 file or a JPEG.

Do *not* try to read a class file as if it's text - you're almost certain to lose information.

Comment: Fun fact: the *strings* in it are in UTF-8. You can see them with `strings Foo.class` *unless* they are mixed up with UTF-8 chars that occupy > 1 byte. You can hide your strings from `strings` by using fancy quotes: `String s = "\u201cFOO\u201d";`

Comment: `Encoding refers to text, not binary data.` - gr8 point refreshed.

Comment: @Vamsh: Please don't ask for votes. It's really not appropriate.

Comment: @g00se, you said `strings Foo.class`. Is `strings` a util/tool or what.

Comment: Yes it's an old Unix tool to find strings in binary files

Comment: @JonSkeet, to upvote good answers, i need 50 reps. thats the point. If at all.. try to encourage new bees on the platform.

Comment: @Vamsh: That doesn't mean it's appropriate to ask people for votes. Please don't do it.

Comment: @g00se to be precise, the embedded strings in a class file use the “Modified UTF-8” format.